# Grouping on two columns and counting distinct values using R

Tags: sql, r, group-by, count, distinct

Using R, I am trying to get two aggregate function max and count distinct and for the values present in a data frame and group them based on two other columns.

```
A = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B')
B = c('R1', 'R2', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R1')
C = c(11, 2, 8, 11, 11, 17)
d = data.frame (A, B, C)

sqldf('select A, B, count(distinct(C)) as UNIQUE_COUNT from d group by A, B')
```

Correct output

```
  A  B UNIQUE_COUNT
1 A R1            2
2 A R2            1
3 B R1            2
4 B R2            1
```

I am able to do that using normal sql using the sqldf package in R. I was trying to do the same using native R to avoid sql. I tried the following query given below but it gave a wrong output.

Wrong query

```
d %>%
group_by(A,B)%>%
summarise(UNIQUE_COUNT = n_distinct(C))
```

Wrong output

```
  UNIQUE_COUNT
1                4
```

Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Code looks fine... but sample data and expected output seem to be missing...

Comment: @RonakShah Done, I have recreated the problem using dummy data

Comment: @Wimpel Done, I have recreated the problem using dummy data

Comment: `d %>%
group_by(A,B)%>%
summarise(UNIQUE_COUNT = n_distinct(C))` works for me...gives me your "Correct Output".

Comment: @RonakShah : Thats strange. It still gives the wrong output for me !!! Wonder if it has anything to do with the libraries?

Comment: I would suggest restart your R session, load `dplyr` only and try again.

Comment: Please also specify which packages you're using.

Comment: In the complete source code, I am using lapply(c("data.table", "sqldf", "dplyr", "caret"), require, character.only = TRUE)

Comment: @RonakShah : Just restarted R and run the same code above. Still getting the wrong output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are probably running `plyr`-package and `dplyr`-package at the same time. They both contain a function named `summarise`. If not plyr, then probably another package that contains a function named `summarise`. 
Run `?summarise` to inspect the available `summarise`-functions on your system.

Make sure you use `summarise()` from the dplyr package!!

```
library( dplyr )
d %>%
  dplyr::group_by(A,B)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(UNIQUE_COUNT = n_distinct(C)) # <-- dplyr

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups:   A [?]
#   A     B     UNIQUE_COUNT
#   <fct> <fct>        <int>
# 1 A     R1               2
# 2 A     R2               1
# 3 B     R1               2
# 4 B     R2               1

d %>%
  dplyr::group_by(A,B)%>%
  plyr::summarise(UNIQUE_COUNT = n_distinct(C))  # <-- plyr

#    UNIQUE_COUNT
# 1            4
```